# How add dictionary inside another dictionary using loops?

Tags: python

```
index = 0
while (condition) :
    ...
    mydict = {"key1":[values], "key2":[values], "key3":[values]}
    somefunction(mydict)

 def somefunc(mydict):
     maindict[index] = mydict
     index = index + 1
     return mydict
 print maindict
```

Output should be like this

```
 maindict = {0:{key1:[values]...}
             1:{key1:[values]...}
             .
             .
             }
```

I'm parsing a file and it contains many data, when the while loop satisfies i get the dictionary called mydict, and i want to add that value into main dictionary using index like 0,1,2.. everytime the loop satifies?

Comment: Not very clear what result you want to get.

Comment: Your code makes no sense, and it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Could you clarify your question? Use valid syntax, provide runnable code, describe the input and what you want to do with the input, that sort of thing?

Comment: You gotta now the depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just from the top of my head (if I understood you correctly):

```
maindict = dict([x, mydict] for x in range(5))
```

Will give you `maindict`:

```
{0: <mydict>, 1: <mydict>, ... , 4: <mydict>}
```

Comment: All the values alias the same `mydict` here, which may be undesirable.

Comment: I am getting error      maindict = dict([index: mydict] for index in range(5))
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: a typo: `[x, mydict]` instead of `[x: mydict]`

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary comprehension:

```
{i: my_dict for i in range(5)}
```